# mrjob: suppress key (or value) in reducer output

Tags: mrjob

By default, mrJob stores the key and the value from output in key[tab]output format.

This happens even if the key (or the value) is empty, null, or otherwise not interesting.  Suppose my key, value pair is None, {"a":1", "b":1}.  Then I get this:

```
None    {"a":1, "b":2}
```

Is there a way to suppress the key or the value?  I just want this:

```
{"a":1, "b":2}
```

BTW, I've already tried this.  Am I missing something...?

```
class MyMrJobClass(MRJob):
    OUTPUT_PROTOCOL = mrjob.protocol.JSONProtocol

    def step1_mapper(self, _, line):
        ...
        yield my_key, my_value

    def step1_reducer(self, key, values):
        for v in values:
            ...
        yield None, my_data

    def steps(self):
        return [
            self.mr(
                mapper=self.step1_mapper,
                reducer=self.step1_reducer,
            ),
        ]
```

NB: I know that I don't need to overwrite steps for a single-step job.  This will eventually be a multistep job, so it's important to build the class that way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `mrjob.protocol.JSONValueProtocol` (notice the **Value**. See the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/protocols.html))  as the output protocol instead of `mrjob.protocol.JSONProtocol`.

The documentation has more information on using [custom protocols](http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/writing-mrjobs.html#job-protocols).